# Java TrueTypeFont

Tags: java, truetype

I'd like to use the TrueTypeFont class from sun.font.TrueTypeFont package in my applet, but Eclipse keeps complaining about the constructor not being visible:

```
import sun.font.TrueTypeFont;
.
.
.    
new TrueTypeFont("a", new Object(), 1, false);
```

yields:

```
    - The constructor TrueTypeFont(String, Object, int, boolean) is not visible
```

Is there a way to fix this? Is there a way to cast `Font` class to `TrueTypeFont`? I need to get data provided by methods of TrueTypeFont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems there:

- `sun.font.TrueTypeFont` is an implementation class that you shouldn't be playing around with.
- It's constructor is "package private" (default access) which means you can't access it from another package (which is what Eclipse happens to be telling you).
- Even if you could access it, an [untrusted] applet cannot access `sun.*` classes (controlled by the `package.access` security property).

Comment: How can I check which packages are available to untrusted applets?